# lightbox with html from php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, lightbox

I'm using jQuery to make a POST which returns html, how can I use this html in my lightbox? Right now I'm using this one: http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/ but I can use any.

php:

```
        $string = "<p> Number:".$num."</p>";
    $string .= "<p>Date:2012  Number: 123</p>";
    $string .= "<table>";
    $string .= "<thead><tr><th>Category</th><th>Status</th><th></th></tr></thead>";
    $string .= "<tbody>";

    foreach ($categories as $cat){
        $string .= "<tr>";
        $string .=      "<td>$cat[C]</td>";
        $string .=      "<td>$cat[S]</td>";
        $string .=      "<td><a href='#'><img src='/images/1.png' /></a></td>";
        $string .= "</tr>";
    }

    $string .= "</tbody>";
    $string .= "</table>";
echo json_encode($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First you should verify that that same html works nicely with buckwilsons lightbox me
2. Then make sure the data returned from your ajax post is the same
3. Place the data on the page where you would like, ex "
4. $('#my_new_html').html(data); //the html data returned from ajax post
5. Within your success function call $('#my_new_html').lightbox_me(); to invoke buckwilsons lightbox on the new element

Hope that helps! Otherwise will need to see more code from you